# Highlight 5 lowest values in a column that are not zero

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, min, minimum

I am using the following custom formula in conditional formatting to try and highlight the 5 lowest values in column B.  However, I would like it to exclude zero values from the data.  How do I highlight the lowest 5 values that are greater than zero?

=$B1<=SMALL($B$1:$B$100,$E$2)

Thank you!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K-dsv3bB1qF-zhPR1XtciHmQAdOMuzrUJU4SlXz5e08/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the zeros before using `SMALL`, like this:

```
=AND($B1,$B1<=SMALL(FILTER($B$1:$B$100,$B$1:$B$100),$E$2))
```

Comment: This ALMOST works.  However, it's only highlighting the bottom 4 instead of 5 for some reason.  Do you know why that's happening?

Comment: this is because the formula has a "less than" symbol instead of "less than or equal to". I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative added in [this tab here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K-dsv3bB1qF-zhPR1XtciHmQAdOMuzrUJU4SlXz5e08/edit#gid=2117494118):

***highest***

```
=xmatch($B1,sortn(filter($B:$B,$B:$B<>0),$E$1,,1,))
```

***lowest***

```
=xmatch($B1,sortn(filter($B:$B,$B:$B<>0),$E$2,,1,1))
```

[image]